# Chromium and Firefox both load very slow on 14.04

Tags: browser

Chromium and Firefox both load very slow on 14.04 upon start. Seems like they take lot of time to open. Please suggest if there is problem in installation or browser. Or if i can run some command and this can solve this issue.

Chromium Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit)

Firefox Quantum 64.0 (32-bit).

Regards,
SHK

Answer (score 0):

I cant guarantee this would work for sure. But still **try deleting all the caches, cookies and unwanted bookmarks**. Firefox and Chromium generates a huge data cache. So initial start up would take up some time. Other probable causes of feeling slow in the browser could be due to :

- Extensions/themes which take huge resources to work or were poorly written
- Try changing your homepage. Problems with a website can cause the browser to take a long time to start

I also experienced the same thing. Doing above workarounds, worked great for me. The above wouldn't completely remove the delay in start up time, but i can assure you that it would certainly reduce it.